# One drive Rest api server bad request 400 when uploading file

Tags: c#, onedrive

this my code for create session and upload file in onedrive

```
            string url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/" + "Nopbackup" +":/" + "" + fileName +":/upload.createSession" + "";

            var result = string.Empty;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            //request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "contentType";
            //request.ac = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", tokenType + " " + accessToken);
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            //byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url);
            //using (Stream st = request.GetRequestStream())
            //    st.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

its giving server bad request  400 error

Comment: Don't know the detail of the service you are invoking, but having "contentType" as ContentTipe and a ContentLength of zero is probably wrong.

Comment: i am using google rest api  POST  /drive/root:/{path_to_item}:/upload.createSession  method this is the link https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the URL you're POSTing with. It looks like this:

```
string url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/" + "Nopbackup" +":/" + "" + fileName +":/upload.createSession" + "";
```

Which turns out to be

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/Nopbackup:/filename:/upload.createSession
```

You've got the colon syntax a little messed up, and the API doesn't know what to do with that (hence the bad request).

Try building the URL like this instead:

```
string url = "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/" + "Nopbackup" + "/" + fileName +":/upload.createSession";
```

And I think things will work better for you.